# In Python how to use row value to refer to columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1)
df=pd.DataFrame(np.c_[np.round(np.random.rand(5,3),1),
   np.random.choice(list('abc'),5)],columns=list('abcd'))
```

[image]

And I wish to use d column content as a lookup and create a new column. For example, row 0 is 'c' will be converted to c column same row content 0.0, and row 1 is 'a' and will be converted to 0.3.

How shall I properly refer to the corresponding columns? Since I need to refer to both row and column, I tried apply (axis =0 or 1), but it only worked on one axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
df['new_col'] = df.lookup(df.index, df['d'])
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

     a    b    c  d new_col
0  0.4  0.7  0.0  c     0.0
1  0.3  0.1  0.1  a     0.3
2  0.2  0.3  0.4  b     0.3
3  0.5  0.4  0.7  b     0.4
4  0.2  0.9  0.0  c     0.0
```